# When do we have $\sup_{x}\int fdy=\int \sup_{x}fdy$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

When do we have $$\sup_{x}\int fdy=\int (\sup_{x}f)dy$$? Here, $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. Some say: Use The monotone convergence theorem, but I really don't understand that hint.

Comment: What don't you understand about the hint?

Comment: From the hint we should have another assumption for $f$ to be increasing in some ways. :)

Comment: @YngwieMalmsteen, now I understood, my problem was the fact that I didn't saw the necessity in doing the limit $lim_{n}f(x_{n},y)=sup_{x} f(x,y)$, as in the first answer bellow. Thanks.

Comment: For $\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+(x-y)^2}$, you have $\sup_x\{f(x, y)\}=1$ for all $y$, but (change of variable $y-x=u$)$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\pi$.